# Relation between rank of matrix over $K$ and over $L\supset K$

Tags: matrices, extension-field, matrix-rank

Let $K$ be a subfield of a larger field $L$ (e.g. $\mathbb{Q}$ over $\mathbb{R}$).
Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix with entries in $K$. Then $A$ can be regarded as either a matrix in $K(m,n)$ or as a matrix in $L(m,n)$. Show that the rank of $A$ is the same in either case.

(I'm thinking that the rank of $A$ is the number of non-zero rows in its row-reduced form, but I don't know how to construct a formal proof.)

Thanks!

Comment: Rank can be defined in a number of different (but equivalent) ways. What is the definition that you are using?

Comment: It is also the number of independent column-vectors. Does this number depend on the ground field?

Comment: The rank is also the size of the largest non-vanishing minor.  What's nice about using this definition is that the role of the extension $K\subset L$ never appears; for considering the number of independent column-vectors, it is not immediately obvious why the introduction of new scalars never makes independent vectors dependent.

Answer (score 2):

The ranking of a matrix is the dimension of the vector space generated by (say) the columns. In either case the generators are in $K^n$ and they span a vector subspace of $K^n$.

So, everything boils down to $\dim_K(V)=\dim_L(V\otimes L)$ which is valid for all $K$-vector spaces $V$.

Comment: Using tensor product to answer this rather elementary question may be a little too much for the asker.